# Title page not generated

Tags: titles

I'm just starting to learn. Faced with such a problem: on the collected PDF file no name and title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\title{Example}
\author{Samvel Safaryan}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \maketitle after begin document.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. Please try to post questions with easy to understand titles so that people can help you.

Comment: I edited your post a little so that it is easier for others to understand what you're asking. Maybe next time you can try to ask your question in that way yourself. Welcome again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\maketitle` was missing in your code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\title{Example} 

\author{Samvel Safaryan}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: My best and sincere wishes for you and your family.